# Matrix equivalent of iota(complex)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

Can the matrix \begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix} be considered the same as '$i$' (where $i^2$ = $-1$) during calculations? It holds for basic properties of $i$ but can it be used for complex calculations?

Comment: The square of a matrix is a matrix, not a number like $-1$. Did you mean $-I$? If so, how are the other complex numbers represented? Are all numbers multiples of $I$?

Comment: @JohnDouma Its square results in the negative of the identity matrix, its cube results in its own additive identity and when raised to the 4th power it gives the identity matrix

Comment: $\left\{aI +b\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}\right\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$

Comment: Try this ... http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/complex/complex.html

Comment: The punchline is that there can be many ways to represent numbers of various types.  Certain representations will showcase certain properties and make them easier to work with.  Other representations might lose certain aspects or at least obfuscate them, making certain properties harder to work with.  The space of $2\times 2$ matrices you allude to can indeed be seen to be homeomorphic (*equivalent in several ways*) to the complex numbers (*and their standard operations*).  You might lose certain things like metrics moving in this direction though.